# iOS Charts library - not able to bind data to chart view

Tags: ios, ios-charts

I am using [charts library](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) and want to display a bar chart. I am facing issue for binding the data to the chart.This is my code.

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var barChartView: BarChartView!
@IBOutlet weak var yearDropDown: UIPickerView!

@IBOutlet weak var rmDropDown: UIPickerView!

@IBOutlet weak var txtYear: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtRm: UITextField!

var months = [String]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

        months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
        let unitsSold = [20.0, 4.0, 6.0, 3.0, 12.0, 16.0, 4.0, 18.0, 2.0, 4.0, 5.0, 4.0]


        getYear()
        setChart(dataPoints: months, values: unitsSold)

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func getYear()
{
    url = RestMonitorServer.baseUrl + "/foo/bar"
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: ["foo": bar,"foo":bar,"foo":bar])
        .responseJSON(){
    (response) in
            print("get year list response ",response)

            if ((response.result.value) != nil) {
                let jsonData = JSON(response.result.value!)

                if jsonData["duration"].arrayObject != nil {
                    self.durationArray.append("duration")
                    print("duration array ", self.durationArray)
                }

            } else if (((response.error)) != nil) {
                let jsonError = response.error
                print("Error in getting year list ", jsonError as Any)
            }

    }

}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    return durationArray.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {


    if pickerView == yearDropDown {

        let titleRow = durationArray[row]

        return titleRow
    }
    return ""
}

func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {

    var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x:values[i],y:Double(i))
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }
    print("data entries ",dataEntries)
    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")
    print("chart data set ", chartDataSet)
    let chartData = BarChartData(dataSets: [chartDataSet])
    print("chart data ",chartData)
    barChartView.data = chartData //error at this line as fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
    print("bar chart data" , barChartView.data!)   
}
```

}

This is my full code. And I am getting error for barChartView which I have initialised as above, but it still giving me error.

Thanks

Comment: is your `barChartView` nil? have you create instance for it?

Comment: I have check your code that work perfect on my side

Comment: Code works fine at my side too!! Please make sure you have initialised "barChartView" if you are not using outlet for chart view.

Comment: Yes I have initialised it as '@IBOutlet weak var barChartView: BarChartView! ' but still getting error .

Comment: I think you haven't gone through the library. Do check out this link for more information - https://www.appcoda.com/ios-charts-api-tutorial/

Comment: I have done every thing as the tutorial says, I am a newbie in iOS development so I not able to understand what exactly is the issue

Comment: Can you post your error which kind of error are you getting ?

Comment: barChartView.data = chartData  //error at this line as fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: I am getting chart data as chart data  <Charts.BarChartData: 0x1464b4b0>

Comment: please try my answer with BarChartView extension.

Comment: @CodeChanger I tried your solution, but it is not working as well, there is something wrong with my barChartView, and it is giving me error as above. Anyways thanks a million for the solution. I shall dig a little deeper.

Comment: One thing I don't understand I have added a view on the view controller and set that view as BarChartView in Identity Inspector. Now when I running the application I am able to see the default text "No chart data available" . But when I am trying to bind the static data. I am getting exception for the BarChartView. Also as you asked before, I have a view with one drop down and a chart. I am populating that UIPickerView with dynamic data. And onClick of the UIPickerView data I have to show the chart data.

Comment: Well I solved the problem, when initialising barChartView I just put a question mark (?) instead of exclamation (!) . Apparently I  was initialising the barChartView as implicit variable. Anyways thank you every one for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my exp you need to move your function to `BarChartView` extension like below :

```
extension BarChartView {

    func setBarChartData(xValues: [String], yValues: [Double], label: String) {

        var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []

        for i in 0..<yValues.count {
            let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: yValues[i])
            dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
        }

        let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: label)
        let chartData = BarChartData(dataSets: [chartDataSet])

        self.data = chartData

    }
}
```

**and Call it like below :**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        barChartView.setBarChartData(xValues: months, yValues: unitsSold, label: "Monthly Sales")
}
```

Try this and let me know is it working or not.

Also one more thing you are setting static data of months & values my question is where are you filling server response data ?